# foreach value passing duplication in web share api javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-7, web-share

I am trying to share the link of a specific product.
In foreach loop, I am calling the products of users so they can share it by pressing share.  The API is working.

But, every button pass the first id there is duplication and i don't have any solution for it...
trying different things since 2 days but all in vein...
please guide me to the solution thank you....

heres the button code

```
@foreach($sellers as $reports)
    <input id="myInput"  type="button" data-name="{{$reports['title']}}" data-id="{{$reports['id']}}" value="{{$reports['id']}}" onclick="addRow(this)">
@endforeach
```

heres the js function

```
    @push('myjs')
    <script>
        function addRow(ele)
        {
            var name= $(ele).attr('data-name');
            var id= $(ele).attr('data-id');

            var text = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/scan-s-report/"+ id +"/landing-page";
            var subject = "Report link for"+ name ;

            console.log(subject);
            $(document).on('click', () => {
                if (navigator.share !== undefined) {
                    navigator.share({
                        // console.log('I m if');
                        text: text,
                        // title: 'Web Share API Draft',
                        // url: 'https://wicg.github.io/web-share/#share-method',
                    })
                        .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
                        .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
                }
                // else {
                //     // console.log('I m else');
                //      window.location = 'mailto:?subject=Report link for + name +&body=http://127.0.0.1:8000/scan-sm-report/+ id +/landing-page';
                // }
            });

        }
    </script>
@endpush
```

@Anurad
[image: @Anurad]

Comment: Did you check html generated of button has unique `data-id` ? Also,what does `id` has ?

Comment: yes they have unique ids

Comment: and id have the id of a row from database

Comment: There are things I think strange: you set the same id for each input and you register on click on the whole document. Normally you would register on click on a button like $(input[type=button]).on('click'). You can then get data inside the function by $(this).data('name')

Comment: okay let me try like this...(y)

Comment: nope not working it is giving an error which i have seen before let me post a picture of it

Comment: the catch part is throwing some exception about user gesture...

Comment: if you use onclick="addRow()" then I think you don't need $().on('click', ...). They are doing the same thing. I think you can move out the code inside () => {...} good luck.

Comment: Thank you.......

Comment: thanks a lot bro... problem solved... i did what you said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use onclick="addRow()" then I think you don't need $().on('click', ...). They are doing the same thing. I think you can move out the code inside () => {...} good luck
@Anurad
this works for me now it is working like a charm :D

```
@push('myjs')
    <script>
        function addRow(ele)
        {
            var name= $(ele).attr('data-name');
            var id= $(ele).attr('data-id');

            var text = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/scan-s-report/"+ id +"/landing-page";
            var subject = "Report link for"+ name ;

            console.log(subject);

        // $('input[type=button]').on('click', () => {
                if (navigator.share !== undefined) {
                    navigator.share({
                        // console.log('I m if');
                        text: text,
                        // title: 'Web Share API Draft',
                        // url: 'https://wicg.github.io/web-share/#share-method',
                    })
                        .then(() => console.log('Successful share'))
                        .catch((error) => console.log('Error sharing', error));
                }
                // else {
                //     // console.log('I m else');
                //      window.location = 'mailto:?subject=Report link for + name +&body=http://127.0.0.1:8000/scan-sm-report/+ id +/landing-page';
                // }
            // });

        }
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: glad I can help!